# receivedMIDIController not calling from sequencer

Tags: audiokit

**Current State:**

- I'm playing a midi file using AppleSequencer.
- VirtualPorts and Listener are implemented, "receivedMIDINoteOn/Off" working great.

**My Problem**

- "receivedMIDIController" not calling from my sequencer.
- Message send from Logic Pro X's MIDI Out Port is calling "receivedMIDIController". (Same MIDI File)

I want to know what is happening, anyone can help me please?

[image: Logic Pro X's MIDI Out Port is calling]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, new track with "replaceMIDINoteData" have only "modiNoteDataEvent"

```
var sequencer:AppleSequencer = AppleSequencer()
let t = sequencer.newTrack("track")
t?.replaceMIDINoteData(with: seqSty.tracks[0].getMIDINoteData())
//sequencer has Note Evnet Only.
```

a sequencer from MIDI Data has all kind of events, and then replace data with "MIDINoteData"

```
sequencer = AppleSequencer(fromData: data)
sequencer.tracks[0].replaceMIDINoteData(with: seqSty.tracks[0].getMIDINoteData())
//sequencer has all events from MIDI
```